# 2sxc Blog paging

Tags: blogs, paging, 2sxc

I don't know if I'm missing something, because I'm new in 2sxc Apps, but I can't find paging option in Blog settings (like it is in the News App).
Does Blog use paging? And if it does - can the number of posts per page be set (and where)?
Thank You all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to StackOverflow :)

I noticed your question was downrated 2x, but don't take this personally, the people who did this probably didn't realize you're new to StackOverflow.

The blog app uses paging, but the setting for it isn't in the view - it's part of the query which feeds the items to the list view. It's just implemented differently - in the blog it's a number in the query, in the News it's a placeholder in the query, which gets the number from the current module.

BTW: since you're new I'll just explain that if this answered your question, best mark it as answered to help people who find this question in future.

Comment: Thank You very much Daniel! 
P.S. 2sxc is fantastic! It took me same time to figure out basic controls, placement and management logic, but when you figure this out – it is quite simple to handle, yet very powerful. Keep up the great work!